# Restart apache2 from linux bash as root

Tags: linux, bash, apache2, command, stdin

I want to restart apache from a bash in linux (OpenSUSE).

I am trying to read the root password from a file (stdin). This is how I do it:

```
exec < /opt/otrsadm/stdin
read a1
sudo apache2ctl -k graceful
echo $a1
```

I get this in my log:

```
[Mon Sep 12 23:23:12 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.101] Restarting apache
[Mon Sep 12 23:23:13 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.101] sudo
[Mon Sep 12 23:23:13 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.101] : 
[Mon Sep 12 23:23:13 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.101] no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

What's my problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sudo -S option reads the password from stdin.

> The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the
>   standard input instead of the terminal device.

```
echo "password" | sudo -S apache2ctl -l graceful
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! And if I want to load the password from a file, how should I write then?

Comment: echo $a1 | sudo -S apache2ctl -l graceful

Comment: Not getting it to work using files, only when I enter the password directly on the line. Isn't this the correct syntax: exec < /opt/otrsadm/stdin,      
read a1,        echo $a1 | sudo -S apache2ctl -l graceful

Comment: What's the error with this change?  If the file has *just* the password you could cat /opt/otrsadm/stdin | sudo -S ...